# What is the proper syntax for usage jinja templates for columns in superset?

Tags: sqlalchemy, jinja2, apache-superset

Here https://superset.apache.org/docs/installation/sql-templating/ described several parameters for handling columns:

- columns: columns which to group by in the query
- groupby: columns which to group by in the query (deprecated)
- table_columns: columns available in the dataset
- time_column: temporal column of the query (None if undefined)

How should I use these parameters?

I've tried this manual https://www.preset.io/blog/intro-jinja-templating-apache-superset/ but this is for values not for columns

Comment: It sounds like these are variables available in the Jinja context. So you could, for example, iterate over the items in `table_columns` list using a Jinja for loop. Can you explain what you’ve tried and how it failed?

Comment: Can you elaborate more ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a syntax for `table_columns` and `time_column`:

```
SELECT 
    {{ ', '.join(table_columns) }}
from my_table where {{ time_column }} < '{{ from_dttm }}'
limit 100
```